# Saying "goodbye" in an elevator

Tags: greeting

When you are leaving an elevator and other people are still in the elevator, how do you say goodbye? Also, what about the reverse situation when you are staying in the elevator. How does it change if the elevator is going up or down?

From observation, I've noticed that people departing usually say 올라가세요 to the people still in the elevator when it is going up. I've haven't really noticed it (probably because it's less common of a situation), but can you say 내려가세요 when the elevator is going down? Are the standard 안녕히 가세요 or 안녕히 계세요 ever appropriate in elevators?  If so, when?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on my common sense as a native speaker, I would say it is quite awkward to say 내려가세요 even when the elevator is going down. And I'll say '들어가세요' when I have to say goodbye, because they are mostly on their way to one's home. If it isn't, which means it's morning so everyone is leaving home, I can say 안녕히 가세요.

So 안녕히 가세요/계세요 also makes sense, by the way. 가세요 when you are remaining, 계세요 when you are leaving, of course. I think 안녕히 가세요 will make sense in almost every single situations: leaving home, returning, remaining in the elevator, etc.